# Python - tkinter; TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas, image-upload

I'm trying to build a graphical interface for image processing. I have problem uploading function.
When I try to check if the file / image exists and modify it, I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

This is my code:

```
import cv2

import instructions as instructions
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = tk.Tk()

logo = Image.open('logo.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
logo_label = tk.Label(image = logo)
logo_label.image = logo
logo_label.grid(column=1,row=0)

def upload():
    browse.set("loading...")
    file = askopenfile(parent=root,mode="rb",title="Choose an image",filetypes =[("JPG file","*.jpg"),("PNG file","*.png"),("JPEG file","*.jpeg")])
    if file:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
        edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)

        color = cv2.bilateralFilter(file,9,250,250)
        cartoon =cv2.bitwise_and(color,color,mask=edges)
        cv2.imshow("Cartoon", cartoon)

intructions = tk.Label(root,text= "Select an image",font = "Raleway")
instructions.grid(columnspan=3,column=0,row=1)



browse = tk.StringVar()
browse_button = tk.Button(root,textvariable = browse,command = lambda:upload(),font = "Raleway",bg="#20bebe",fg ="white",width=15,height =2)
browse.set("Browse")
browse_button.grid(column=1,row=2)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = 600,height = 300)
canvas.grid(columnspan = 3)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line no 20: you are using CvtColor to change the image to grayscale.
`gray = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` you need to pass the file pointer in place of file.
That is why you are getting the error `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

You need to :
First read the file using `img=cv2.imread(file)`, and then use 
CvtColor on the img data using `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`.

So delete the content in line 20 and add

```html
img=cv2.imread(file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Edit: 
One important thing on line 6 you are importing askopenfile which returns a binary encoded path of the image. This is wrong implementation.
Instead you should import askopenfilename; this returns the path of the image file.

I am sharing the entire updated code here :

```html
import cv2
import tkinter as tk

import instructions as instructions
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tk.Tk()

logo = Image.open('logo.jpg')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
logo_label = tk.Label(image = logo)
logo_label.image = logo
logo_label.grid(column=1,row=0)

def upload():
    browse.set("loading...")
    file = askopenfilename(parent=root,title="Choose an image",filetypes =[("JPG file","*.jpg"),("PNG file","*.png"),("JPEG file","*.jpeg")])
    print(file)
    if file:
        img=cv2.imread(file)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
        edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)

        color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,250,250)
        cartoon =cv2.bitwise_and(color,color,mask=edges)
        cv2.imshow("Cartoon", cartoon)

intructions = tk.Label(root,text= "Select an image",font = "Raleway")
instructions.grid(columnspan=3,column=0,row=1)



browse = tk.StringVar()
browse_button = tk.Button(root,textvariable = browse,command = lambda:upload(),font = "Raleway",bg="#20bebe",fg ="white",width=15,height =2)
browse.set("Browse")
browse_button.grid(column=1,row=2)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = 600,height = 300)
canvas.grid(columnspan = 3)
root.mainloop()
```

This should work let me know.
Hope this solves your purpose

Comment: I have added the entire updated code. This works on mine. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an image to `cv2.cvtColor`, you are currently passing a string -  `file`.

```py
    if file:
        src = cv2.imread(file)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
```

Comment: TypeError: Can't convert object of type '_io.BufferedReader' to 'str' for 'filename'